# Batch writing variables to file not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch and i have this code:

```
@echo off
set var1 = line1
set var2 = line2
echo %var1% >output.txt
echo %var2% >output.txt
```

I found on Google that you can use `>` to send the output to a text file. But when i look at the text file all i get is a file that says `line2`. Can any one help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo whatever >  file.txt` will overwrite the file and place new content in it

`echo whatever >> file.txt` will append to the file

Comment: Thanks hard to believe all I was missing was an extra >.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `spaces` around the equals signs.  The spaces are included in the variable name as well as the content of the variables.